# How to use sum() function in SQL Query and also selecting a column

Tags: database, oracle

I am new to Database side. I need to sum up two columns and also I need to fetch data from a particular column. So I have written a query like this:

```
select orderid,sum(productid),sum(price) from orderdetails
```

but this returning an error stating

```
not a single-group group function
```

Please guide us on this.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add a `group by` statement:

```
select orderid,sum(productid),sum(price) from orderdetails group by orderid
```

Comment: Do we know what the asker actually wants here?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I guess Jens gave him a correction for the query

Answer (score 1):

> you can't simply select a column with the other aggregate function call,if you
>   really want, then you need to use aggregate function with that
>   column(`orderid`) too or you need to place that particular column
>   (`orderid`) in `group by` claus.

like this:

```
select max(orderid),sum(productid),sum(price) from orderdetails
```

or

```
select orderid,sum(productid),sum(price) from orderdetails group by orderid
```

See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173454.aspx) other Aggregate functions.

Answer (score 1):

```
select orderid,sum(productid),sum(price) from orderdetails group by orderid
```

whenever you use aaggregate function and you want to select some columns you simply put all the columns before the aggregate function and add a group by to that columns